# How to access macros in IronPython

Tags: c, macros, ironpython

It´s possible using Macros in ironPython?
I have a dll with macros in C and I would like access it from IronPython.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access C macros from a DLL - they're handled by the C preprocessor, so they never reach the compiler and thus can't part of the DLL. You can access functions exported from the DLL in IronPython using the standard Python [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module.